# Why calling super's hitTest doesn't cause infinite loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, event-handling

I meet the above question while dealing with touch outside the border of the specified view. The solution I found on website tells me to override hitTest:Event: method like this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UIView *view = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
if (view == nil) {
    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        CGPoint tp = [subView convertPoint:point fromView:self];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(subView.bounds, tp)) {
            view = subView;
        }
    }
}
return view;
```

}

I've noticed that in the first line the author calls `[super hitTest:point withEvent:event]`, and I'm also aware that the hit test is recursive. So the super must call subview's hitTest method and the later one will call super again. I just wonder why it doesn't cause infinite loop? Thanks!

Comment: In the same way how viewDidLoad() doesn't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Aren't you mixing sub**views** and sub**classes**?

Comment: Thanks. I trully misunderstood the point. I just simplly mixed up super and superView. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You understand it wrong, super doesn't call `hitTest` method on subviews, it calls `pointInside` method.
From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest?language=objc):

> This method traverses the view hierarchy by calling the
> pointInside:withEvent: method of each subview to determine which
> subview should receive a touch event.

Hope it helps!